# C Function returning pointer to first element vs. a pointer to an entire array

Tags: c, api-design

Suppose I have an API function which returns a pointer to some memory, that is later to be consumed in an array-like manner. Suppose also that its size is known in advance, and that it's declared like so:

```
returntype API(void);
```

Is it better for the function's return type to be declared as pointer to an array, like so:

```
typedef struct data (*returntype)[];
```

or for it to be defined as simply the good old pointer to the first element, like so:

```
typedef struct data *returntype;
```

On one hand returning a pointer to an entire array seems to make more sense, but on the other the API consumer would probably prefer the 2nd version because it's easier to consume:

e.g. from the consumer's perspective, copying the 3rd `struct` in the array:

1st declaration:

```
returntype = API();
struct data third= (*returntype)[2];
```

2nd declaration:

```
returntype = API();
struct data third = returntype[2];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The defacto standard would be option 2: to return a pointer to the first element of the array.

Your first option is actually a pointer to a pointer to the first element of the array: `typedef struct data** returntype;` You can of course do this, but that second level of indirection implies a second order array. ie: `typedef struct data (returntype)[][];` Which is perfect if your data fits that description.